# Android(XMPP)cant get Presence packets but can get Message packets without using default Roster

Tags: android, android-intent, xmpp, packets

I built an im application and can succesfully chat with an other user.(with Xmpp,Smack). Now I wanted to get presence updates( when a user becomes online or offline (I do not care about the rest)) so I tried to apply the same code I used for messages to presences.(We have custom iqs we do not use the Roster of other classes)

```
public void listeningForMessages() {
        PacketFilter filter = new AndFilter(new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class));
        PacketCollector collector = mConnection.createPacketCollector(filter);
while (true) {
        Packet packet = collector.nextResult();


        if (packet instanceof Presence) {
            Presence newPresence = (Presence) packet;
            String fromPresence = newPresence.getFrom();
            String contactJidPresence = "";
            if (fromPresence.contains("/")) {
                contactJidPresence = fromPresence.split("/")[0];
                Log.d(TAG, "The real jid is :" + contactJidPresence);
            } else {
                contactJidPresence = fromPresence;
            }
            if (newPresence != null) {
                System.out.println("Received availability update from "
                        + contactJidPresence + " : "
                        + (newPresence != null ? (packet) : "NULL"));
                Handler handler1 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                toastThis = contactJidPresence;
                handler1.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Your UI code here
                        if (!ChatActivity.active) {
                            Toast.makeText(mApplicationContext, " You received a  presence from " + toastThis, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
//Rest of the logic
}
}
```

I get the messages with the same way in the same while(true) statement and I can get them.But I do not get any presence updates(they are added to my "customroster" in server-side). For your conveinence I ll also copy how I get the messages but they are same.

```
if (packet instanceof Message) {
                Message message = (Message) packet;
                String from = message.getFrom();
                String contactJid = "";
                if (from.contains("/")) {
                    contactJid = from.split("/")[0];
                    Log.d(TAG, "The real jid is :" + contactJid);
                } else {
                    contactJid = from;
                }
                if (message != null && message.getBody() != null) {
                    System.out.println("Received message from "
                            + contactJid + " : "
                            + (message != null ? message.getBody() : "NULL"));
```

Now after that I also send an intent with this but it doesnt matter in my question(I think because I dont even get a Presence packet so it never goes inside if statement)

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(ConnectionService.NEW_MESSAGE);
                intent.setPackage(mApplicationContext.getPackageName());
                intent.putExtra(ConnectionService.BUNDLE_FROM_JID, contactJid);
                intent.putExtra(ConnectionService.BUNDLE_MESSAGE_BODY, message.getBody());
                mApplicationContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Please update plugins in your open-fire server. May be it require.

Comment: So you think the code is correct? We can get the packets in our server I think the problem is with android

Comment: I personally prefer Roaster. But please make sure all the plugins in whatever server is used are correct and updated? Because at some place if you are right then still not getting desire output at Android side. Please cross verify your server configuration.

Comment: So if they are not updated the code wont enter the if packet instanceof presence part since I do not receive any presence packets right?